# Sencha Cmd 3.1.2 missing dependencies.js

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

When running 'sencha app build package' Im geeting error code 255 and it says dependecies.js file is missing. Anyone with same 'issue'?
It's linux-64 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by removing:

```
v2deps=true
```

from sencha.cfg